# Connect to database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, server

I've made a database on my server but can't reach it.

I tried to connect to the database using php:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die(mysql_error());
```

I get this message:

*Warning : mysql_connect (): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time , or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ New Site Ron (app) \ connection.php on line 7*

Is it because I'm using xampp or is it something else?

Thanks in advance,

Sam

---

I fixed it by using my sever instead of using xampp.

Comment: 1) mysql_* is deprecated. 2) if you're on the same machine as $host use "localhost".

Comment: your connection timed out. e.g. the tcp port is firewalled and silently dropping packets.

Comment: Did you maybe create a database on remote server and trying to access it from your local machine?

Comment: I created a database on the server (mijndomein.nl). And I'm trying to access it with xampp. I guess I need to email mijndomein.nl for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't connect to MySQL at "thehostnameyouprovided.com" either ... not on port 3306 anyway.

So either the MySQL daemon/server isn't running there, or it's not running on TCP/IP 3306 (for example, it's only running on a local socket), or the server has a firewall that isn't allowing access to me from my IP address (and might not be allowing it to your from your address either).

At any rate, making absolutely sure the server is accepting connections from your address on port 3306 should be your first line of inquiry.

Comment: Incidentally, it might be a good idea to edit your post and redact the hostname from your script (posting it to millions of geeks on S.O. might gain a little *too much* interest in your DB server if you catch my meaning...)